# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.data.Tuple

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

i am getting following error while running pig script. My script is running fine in grant shell. i am getting this error while running through 'time pig' .

pig version - Apache Pig version 0.11.0-cdh4.6.0

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.data.Tuple
    at org.apache.pig.data.BinInterSedes.readBag(BinInterSedes.java:237)
    at org.apache.pig.data.BinInterSedes.readDatum(BinInterSedes.java:349)
    at org.apache.pig.data.BinInterSedes.readDatum(BinInterSedes.java:313)
    at org.apache.pig.data.utils.SedesHelper.readGenericTuple(SedesHelper.java:144)
    at org.apache.pig.data.BinInterSedes.readDatum(BinInterSedes.java:344)
    at org.apache.pig.data.BinInterSedes.readDatum(BinInterSedes.java:313)
    at org.apache.pig.data.utils.SedesHelper.readGenericTuple(SedesHelper.java:144)
    at org.apache.pig.data.BinInterSedes.readTuple(BinInterSedes.java:144)
    at org.apache.pig.data.BinInterSedes.readTuple(BinInterSedes.java:1286)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.io.NullableTuple.readFields(NullableTuple.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDese
```

Comment: add your code in question

Answer (score 1):

Please share your code so that we can a better picture.
From what you have posted, check the following-

> - Are you using a variable where a tuple is required? If yes, then you should specify a field from a relation instead.
> - Are you using an explicit cast in your script or can you figure if there's an implicit cast being used by Pig for some reason like for comparison or join etc.? If yes, then you should try to make sure that these statements are comparing fields with same schemas.